# How can I add a variable to an "it" statement in an rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

If I have

```
let(:analysis_file_1) { "./spec/test_files/analysis1.json" }
...
it "should have message x" do
```

I'd like to print out the value of analysis_file_1 in the "it" statement.

But this doesn't work:

```
it "#{analysis_file_1} should have message x" do
```

It errors out with

```
in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `analysis_file_1' for #<Class:0x007f865a219c00> (NameError)
```

Is there a way to use a let defined variable in an it message?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `analysis_file_1` as a local?

Comment: what does your "doesn't work" print out?

Comment: @rogerdpack, ` #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `analysis_file_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a constant like this:

```
ANALYSIS_FILE_1 = "./spec/test_files/analysis1.json"

it "#{ANALYSIS_FILE_1} should have message x" do
```

Or in case you have multiple analysis files you can put them in an array:

```
["./spec/test_files/analysis1.json", "./spec/test_files/analysis2.json", "./spec/test_files/analysis3.json"].each do |analysis_file|
  it "#{analysis_file} should have message x" do
    # Your spec here
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to use a symbol:

```
it "#{:analysis_file_1} should have message x"
```

==

As Peter Klipfel suggested, declaring a local variable works for me:

```
analysis_file_1 = "./spec/test_files/analysis1.json"

it "#{analysis_file_1} should have message x" do
```

I couldn't get sevenseacat's suggestion to work. This:

```
describe "Joe" do
  subject(:last) { "Smith" }

  it "should have message x"  do 
    pending
  end
end
```

produced the output:

```
Pending:
  Joe should have message x
    # No reason given
    # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:6
```

I expected the output to be:

```
Pending:
  Joe Smith should have message x
```

Comment: No, this just prints out "analysis_file_1" instead of the value.

Comment: @ScottWilson, Arrgh.  You are right.  Sorry about that, I misinterpreted my results.